# Performance Problems with jQuery animate

Tags: jquery, performance, firefox, jquery-animate, parallax

I created a little parallax animation with jQuery. It runs smooth in Safari but it's very jerky in Firefox. Both on Mac. Maybe you can help me. Thanks!

This is my code:

```js
var bgx = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {

 $(this).click(function(){
     $("#cheat").append('<img src="images/cheat.gif"></img>');
     $("#bike").animate({top: '250px', }, 10000);
 }); 
 
 parallax();

 function parallax(){
        console.log(counter);
        $("#background1").animate({backgroundPosition: bgx-=1000}, 100000, "linear");
        $("#background2").animate({backgroundPosition: bgx-=1000}, 80000, "linear");
        $("#background3").animate({backgroundPosition: bgx-=1000}, 50000, "linear");
        $("#background4").animate({backgroundPosition: bgx-=1000}, 10000, "linear", parallax);
    }
});
```

Comment: Please supply more of the code that is causing the issue. What are the elements being referred to? Where does the variable 'counter' get declared and altered? What is 'bgx' used for? For a question regarding a performance issue, more than a few lines of isolated code is needed.

Comment: Ok, just tried this (with my own images - so won't be the same size etc.), and it's fine in IE, choppy in FF and Chrome (all PC). It may be better to try CSS animations and transitions rather than performing animation in a loop. I'd go with one or the other - loop and adjust the position (not great), or CSS (better). It looks like you are entering the loop, starting an animation, and then hitting the loop again (almost immediately) before the first animation has completed. The loop is accumulating animations.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, here is the complete code with some comments in the script.js. The counter had no function.

```js
var bgx = 0; //value for background-position

$(document).ready(function() {

 $(this).click(function(){
     $("#cheat").append('<img src="images/cheat.gif"></img>');
     $("#bike").animate({top: '250px', }, 10000);
 }); 
 
 parallax(); //

 function parallax(){ //animate the background-position
        $("#background1").animate({backgroundPosition: bgx-=1000}, 100000, "linear");
        $("#background2").animate({backgroundPosition: bgx-=1000}, 80000, "linear");
        $("#background3").animate({backgroundPosition: bgx-=1000}, 50000, "linear");
        $("#background4").animate({backgroundPosition: bgx-=1000}, 10000, "linear", parallax); //recall function
    }
});
```

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: black;
}
img {
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    position: absolute;
}
#background0 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    background-image: url(../images/bg0.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-color: green;
}
#background1 {
 width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    background-image: url(../images/bg1.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: 0;
}
#background2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    background-image: url(../images/bg2.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: 0;
}
#background3 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    background-image: url(../images/bg3.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: 0;
}
#background4 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 4;
    background-image: url(../images/bg4.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: 0;
}
#bike {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 top: 635px;
 left: 45%;
 position: absolute;
    z-index: 4;
}
#cheat {
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>MS01</title>
  <link href="css/style1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
 </head>

 <body>
  <div id="background0"></div>
  <div id="background1"></div>
  <div id="background2"></div>
  <div id="background3"></div>
  <div id="background4"></div>

  <div id="bike"><img src="images/car.png"></div>

  <div id="cheat"></div>
 </body>

</html>
```

```js
var bgx = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {

 $(this).click(function(){
     $("#cheat").append('<img src="images/cheat.gif"></img>');
     $("#bike").animate({top: '250px', }, 10000);
 }); 
 
 parallax();

 function parallax(){
        console.log(counter);
        $("#background1").animate({backgroundPosition: bgx-=1000}, 100000, "linear");
        $("#background2").animate({backgroundPosition: bgx-=1000}, 80000, "linear");
        $("#background3").animate({backgroundPosition: bgx-=1000}, 50000, "linear");
        $("#background4").animate({backgroundPosition: bgx-=1000}, 10000, "linear", parallax);
    }
});
```